# How to remove a github repository from my view

Tags: github

[Github Website Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44xqW.png) I just opened an issue on github. After I closed the issue, I found that the vscode public repository is still in my github repository list. How can I remove it from my view? The VsCode public repo has no relation to me and I wanted to remove it from My Repositories. When I searched for all types of repositories, i can't find this public repo. Can somebody figure it out how to remove this public repo?
Note: There is no SETTINGS part as it is a public repo and does not belong to me.

Comment: Do you mean the my repositories list on the Github web interface or a list of repositories in vsc?

Comment: @dan1st I just uploaded an image. Please refer to that and Thank you very much for helping me !

Comment: I don't think this is possible if you contributed to the repository...